# How do I interrupt the thread and ask it to complete its work when exit has been pressed by user?

Tags: java, multithreading

The following snippet is a thread named "Foo" that sleeps for 1 minute and then copies the data typed in *1 minute* to a log file.

```
         while(isStarted) {
           try {
              Thread.sleep(60000); // sleep for 1 minute
              ArrayList<String> keyStrokeList = nativeMethods.getKeyStrokeList();
              int result = copy.copyToLogFile(keyStrokeList);
              System.out.println(result);
           } catch(Exception exc) {
               exc.printStackTrace();
             }
         }
```

I will describe one situation :

*Foo* thread has  finished copying all the data typed in last one minute and it has been 30 seconds since it is asleep. This thread unaware of the situation that several keys are being tapped when it is asleep,will never be able to copy the key strokes into the log file when one presses `System.exit(0)`.

Is there any way I can interrupt this thread *i.e awake it and ask it to copy the data to the log file*.

Please discuss how should I approach this problem.

**The situation in the question :**

```
loop started

thread is sleeping and will sleep for 1 minute

after a minute,it gets the keys tapped in the last 1 minute and copies all that
to a file

Thread sleeps again..and will sleep for 1 minute before it copies the keystrokes

It has been about 30 seconds and thread will sleep for 30 seconds more before it starts
copying the key strokes

suddenly the user presses exit button in the application

The user wants that key strokes be recorded till the second he presses exit

I cannot do System.exit(0) before checking the thread is asleep or not

How do I do this. Should I awake it or make a different call to the list and get the 
key strokes because they are being recorded ? And how shall I awake it ?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're part way there...

```
while(isStarted) {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(60000); // sleep for 1 minute
    } catch(InterruptedException exc) {
        exc.printStackTrace();
    }
    ArrayList<String> keyStrokeList = nativeMethods.getKeyStrokeList();
    int result = copy.copyToLogFile(keyStrokeList);
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

What you need to is provide a way to terminate the loop...

```
public void dispose() {
    isStarted = false;
    interrupt();
    try {
        join();
    } catch(InterruptedException exc) {
        exc.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

You should also know that the JVM will not exit until all non-daemon threads have completed (under normal shutdown).  This means you can call `System.exit(0)` and the JVM will not terminate until the logger thread has terminated.

You could use this, but attaching a [shut down hook](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook%28java.lang.Thread%29) which would have the capacity to call the `dispose` method on the logger thread...just a thought

Comment: Will this simple step `new Thread("Foo").interrupt` not awake and perform the pending task ?

Comment: No, you've not started the thread, and you've still got the issue of the loop condition to overcome. But yes, a call to the instance of the logger thread interrupt method will cause the sleep method to terminate prematually

Comment: If I make the condition false and call interrupt on foo's instance , will the statements after the sleep execute ?

Comment: Yes. It will act as if the sleep method returns normally, the code after the sleep will execute and the the loop condition will cheeked and the loop will be existed and the thread will terminate

Comment: If you're interested in the state of the thread, you can check [Thread#interrupted](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupted()) or [Thread#isInterruoted](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#isInterrupted())

Comment: `java.lang.InterruptedException: sleep interrupted` gets thrown when I do `thread.interrupt()` and keys are not logged when I press exit and  _0 < time-elapsed < 60_

Comment: I have witnessed that your earlier comment _"It will act as if the sleep method returns normally, the code after the sleep will execute.."_ has proved to be wrong. Instead an exception ` 
java.lang.InterruptedException: sleep interrupted` is thrown. Therefore I added the code to copy the keys taps in `Exception` block and it is working now.

Comment: Firstly, you are right, but in my code example, I wrap the exception only around the sleep statement (unlike the OP), which means, from the perspective of my example, it's as if the sleep statement returned normally. Second, in the context of my example, there is no need to add more code to the exception handler

Comment: Yeah.  And can you please explain why have used `join` in your sample code?  Just interrupting the thread doesn't complete the task?  I mean what good does `join` do?

Comment: Join just makes sure that thread has completed (and the last write operation was competed). This is especially useful if thread is up as daemon thread

Answer (score 0):

You should use a shared object between 2 thread to implement wait/notify pattern instead of Thread.sleep(..) method.

In your condition, there are 2 threads:

- Which reads buffer at 1 min interval. (Thread1)
- Which will receive "exit" event first. (Thread2)

So, whenever you create instance of Thread1 you can pass a Java Object (new Object()) to it. Reader thread can be put into sleep using object.wait(60*1000); So it will sleep for max 1 minute if object.notify() is not called in 1 minute. If object.notify() is called in this duration, thread will immediately resume.

So, whenever user wants to exit from application you can call object.notify(); which will resume reader thread.

If I failed to explain you the solution due to my bad English please let me know. I will provide you a code sample.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fairly simple test case to show a way to do this:

```
public class InterruptTest
{
    @Test
    public void test() throws InterruptedException
    {
        //Create the logging thread and start it
        LogRunnable runnable = new LogRunnable();
        Thread t = new Thread(runnable);
        t.start();

        //Wait some time
        Thread.sleep(3500);

        System.out.println("User has pressed exit, starting shutdown");

        //Tell the runnable to shut down
        runnable.halt();
        //Interrupt the thread to wake it up
        t.interrupt();
        //Wait until thread terminates
        t.join();

        System.out.println("Exiting");
    }

    private static class LogRunnable implements Runnable
    {
        private static final int SLEEPMS = 2000;

        private boolean isStarted = true;
        private int runCount = 1;

        public void halt()
        {
            this.isStarted = false;
        }

        public void run()
        {
            while(isStarted)
            {
                try
                {
                    Thread.sleep(SLEEPMS);
                }
                catch(InterruptedException e)
                {
                    System.out.println("Interrupted");
                }
                catch(Exception exc)
                {
                    exc.printStackTrace();
                }

                //Do work
                System.out.println("Work done " + runCount++);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Work done 1
User has pressed exit, starting shutdown
Interrupted
Work done 2
Exiting
```

- When the user presses the exit key, you signal your main thread to start shutting everything down (in the test-case, it simply waits for some time)
- The logging thread is told to halt and awakened via a [interrupt()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupt%28%29) -call
- Before exiting, the main thread calls [join()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join%28%29) to wait until the logging thread has completed, you could consider using an overload that takes a timeout in case something goes wrong
- The logging thread wakes up with `InterruptedException`, completes the code after the catches and terminates
- After the logging thread has terminated, the main-thread returns from the `join()`-call and terminates